# Querying a set in Hive if it contains

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I have the below, which gives me a set in hive

```
collect_set(quotaname)
```

Sample output:

```
["Quota1", "Quota2"]
```

I have tried to use `contains` or `LIKE` operator, but I can't figure out how to say `If the last item in the set = X then...`

Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_contains`:

```
hive> select array_contains(array("Quota1", "Quota2"),'Quota2');
OK
true
Time taken: 0.144 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select array_contains(array("Quota1", "Quota2"),'Quota3');
OK
false
Time taken: 0.096 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

For accessing last item in a set, use `set[size(set)-1]`:

```
with mydata as (
 select array('Quota1', 'Quota2') as myset
)
select case when myset[size(myset)-1] = 'Quota2' then 'Contains!' else 'No' end from mydata ;
```

Result:

```
OK
Contains!
Time taken: 3.375 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

You can use `LIKE` operator: `myset[size(myset)-1] LIKE '%Quota%'`, etc, etc